# TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier

Tags: c#, oracle

I've created dataset and can preview data with table adapters.  But when I run the program, OracleConnection initialized with same connection string throws  TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier!  Why it works in designer but doesn't when I run it?

Here is what I've got:

```
MYTNS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.220.90)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYTNS )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Have you verified that your program is finding the correct tnsnames file?

Comment: From a command line run TNSPING against MYTNS and confirm that it is using the expected tnsnames file.  Post the output.

Comment: 32bit. i had 9 and 11g oracle clients.  Perhaps they were meddling with each other.  I killed all and install 10g client.  It works and the problem is solved but question remains open.  What does TNSPING do?

Comment: TNSPing tests if you can connect to a remote listener.  It doesn't check if the database behind the listener is up, but does allow you to see if the listener exists and is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanx guys for your input.  It helped me in general to understand how this works.  But it seems that the problem is in environment variable "path" and machine.config.  When running designer, it reads info from registry and succusfully finds all dlls needed, but at the runtime it uses path.  So, you just put your chunk of path that points to ORA home infront.
Manipulating path is a well known recipe, however before you gain a deeper understanding of how ora provider .NET works you'll end up trying everything that you know of brainlessly.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your problem has already been solved, but I figured I would add this in case someone else came along in the future.

I have had this same issue before and have used SysInternals Process Monitor to see that my application was attempting to retrieve the tnsnames file of an older oracle install on my machine.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Could you explain further how you used Process Monitor to make that determination?

Comment: @Mike - I don't quite remember all of the specifics now (being two years later), but I do remember that when you run process monitor you will be able to filter by the PID of your application. Once you do that you will see tns names files being accessed in the "Path" column.  I believe they will be part of a "ReadFile" operation, but don't quote me on that.